# Joomla SEF url in CLI script

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, category, cli

I am new to Joomla, I am writing a script under folder cli. I am calling helper file of admin component where I fetch category and return url of category.

The function in helper is fine and works well when executed through admin menu.

The issue is with category URL not being generated when used in cli script.

```
$app    = JApplication::getInstance('site'); 
$router = &$app->getRouter();     
$newUrl = ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute('10'); 
$newUrl = $router->build($newUrl); 
$url = $newUrl->toString(); 
$url = str_replace('/administrator', '', $url);
```

when used with CLI it throws error for strict standards for `$router = &$app->getRouter();`

i have also tried

> JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute('10'));

It just throws error saying failed to start application.

I want to get SEF url of category so that I can also get it returned in my cli file.

My cli code:

```
class Abc extends JApplicationCli
{
    public function doExecute()
    {
        JFactory::getSession()->gc();

        JLoader::register('AbcHelper',JPATH_BASE.'/administrator/components/com_abc/helper.php');
        $url = AbcHelper::getUrl();
        echo $url;
    }
}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('Abc')->execute();
```

helper.php

```
public static function getUrl()
{
    $url='';
    $app    = JApplication::getInstance('site');
    $router = &$app->getRouter();    
    $newUrl = ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute('10');
    $newUrl = $router->build($newUrl);
    $url = $newUrl->toString();
    $url = str_replace('/administrator', '', $url);
    return $url;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use factory to get site application: Also looks like `ContentHelperRoute` is missing. You have import it. The strict standards can be solved by removing the ampersand before `getRouter()` call.

```
public static function getUrl()
{
    // Register required classes.
    JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');

    // Get site router.
    $router = JFactory::getApplication('site')->getRouter('site');

    // Build URI object.
    $url = $router->build(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute('10'));

    return $url->toString();
}
```

> i have also tried
>
> > JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute('10'));
>
> It just throws error saying failed to start application.

`JRoute::_()` will not work in CLI because it's based on current application and CLI doesn't have a router. `JRoute::link()` should work but, apparently, it has the same issue at the moment.

Comment: & is already there and it throws error "PHP Strict standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference" adding JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');
does not help

Comment: if i remove & then it throws error "failed to start application"

Comment: Use `JFactory::getApplication('site')` to get the application.

Comment: can you please also suggest how can i use "rtrim( JURI::root(), '/') . JRoute::_('', true, 1);" in cli?

Comment: `JRoute::_()` does not and will not work in CLI. `JRoute::_link()` but it currently has a bug which prevents it from working in CLI. `JUri::root()` issuecan only be solved by manually setting `$live_site` option in `configuration.php`.